# How to show particular cms page for specific user group?

Tags: magento2, customer-group, cms-pages

I want to show different homepage for wholesale customer.

Comment: so you want two homepages one for normal customer and one for wholesale?

Comment: Yes, i want to  display different page to wholesale customer.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create di.xml in your custom module under Namespace\Module\etc directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index">
        <plugin name="restrict_home_page" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Cms\Controller\Index\Index" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

2. Create Index.php under Namespace\Module\Plugin\Cms\Controller\Index.

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Cms\Controller\Index;

class Index
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Helper\Page
     */
    protected $pageHelper;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;

    /**
     * Index constructor.
     * 
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Helper\Page $pageHelper
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Helper\Page $pageHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->pageHelper = $pageHelper;
        $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $coreRoute = null
    ) {
        $group = $this->httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_GROUP);
        $pageId = 0;
        if($group == 1) {
            $pageId = 2;
        } else if($group == 2) {
            $pageId = 5;
        }
        if($pageId) {
            $resultPage = $this->pageHelper->prepareResultPage($subject, $pageId);
            if (!$resultPage) {
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward $resultForward */
                $resultForward = $this->resultForwardFactory->create();
                $resultForward->forward('defaultIndex');
                return $resultForward;
            }

            return $resultPage;
        } else {
            return $proceed($coreRoute);
        }
    }
}
```